# Why do i need *public-api.ts* and also *exports*

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular-library

I am new to angular,

started writing my first library, containing components, services, directives.

i listed my components, services, directives in the library's `exports` array, but still:

- When using the library form another library or application, and to compile successfully,
  i needed to list my components and services in the `public-api.ts`.  why ? isn't the ngModule's  `exports` array enough?
- now deleted the components,services, directives from the `exports` array and everything still works. why ?

reading around the docs at angular.io, it looks like `public-api.ts` and `exports` serve the same purpose - i am probably missing something basic here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `exports` of a `@NgModule` defines what is exposed to other modules when that module is imported in the `imports` of another module.  The `public-api` acts as a barrel file for cleaner path imports.

#### Example:

```
// Instead of this
import { ExampleService } from '@lib/services/example.service';
import { AntoherService } from '@lib/sevivces/another.service';

// You can do this
import { ExampleService, AnotherService } from '@lib';
```

> https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#exports
> https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel

Comment: Does public_api.ts just a convention, but this still doesn't stop users from importing something inside the Angular library?

Answer (score 8):

exports in ngModule act as Angular part of export, and public-api.ts export typescript symbol of your component/pipe/directive.

The second export is not required but recommended to keep your import path clean.

with public-api.ts (recommended)

```
import {A, B, C} from 'my-library'
```

without public-api.ts

```
import {A} from 'my-library/a'
import {B} from 'my-library/b'
import {C} from 'my-library/c'
```

inside your my-module.module.ts (works well but not as smart as public-api.ts)

```
import {A, B, C} from 'my-library/my-module'
```